# PHP -> HTML tags are not rendering in html code

Tags: php, html, css

[image: Screenshot]

I am a high school student who is trying to make own website. If I write only block element, it works properly but If it is in html code, not working. That is like inline elements. Sometimes works, sometimes not. No idea what happened.

That is what I have written:

```php
<?php
echo "<div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div><div>test</div>";
?>
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: If the PHP is generating the rendered HTML that you expect, then it is not a PHP issue.  If the expected rendered HTML does not _display_ the way that you expect it to, then it is probably a CSS issue.

Comment: You should probably read this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want it to be a vertical list instead of a horizontal one, the reason it's going horizontal is your newsfeed class has `display: flex;` set, removing this will make it the same as the one at the top

[image]

Inside your index.css file, this is the section that's affecting it becoming a vertical list

```
.newsfeed{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex; // this line
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

This should be tagged under #html or #css, as it's not the PHP that's causing the issue.

Comment: Ah, yes. I have forgotten about that. Thank you!